# How do you define the portion of a game's result that is accounted for by chance?

Tags: games

I'm not sure if there's an established way of defining the concept I'm describing, but every game that can be played involving a random component — dice, coins, or otherwise — has a certain amount of the result of that game that is determined by chance, and a certain amount of the result of that game that is determined by skill.

How does one define the portion of a game that is determined by change vs. skill, and what terms can I research to gain a better understanding of this concept?